# RStudio * checking package dependencies ... ERROR

Tags: r, dependencies, package, rstudio

this has now been bugging me for a while now and I can't make other related pieces of advice fit to my problem. Yes, i have perused the net for help.

Problemstatement:
I have written a package with all the basic requirements to make a first build.
However, I have two dependecies (functions from other packages) which seemingly can't be loaded.

```
==> Rcmd.exe build mypackage
```

[...]

```
* using log directory 'mydirectory/mypackage.Rcheck'
* using R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
* using platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32 (64-bit)
* using session charset: ISO8859-1
* checking for file 'mypackagel/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
* checking extension type ... Package
* this is package 'mypackage' version '0.01'
* checking package namespace information ... OK
* checking package dependencies ... ERROR
 Package required but not available: 'otherpackage'

Exited with status 1.
```

Now I am using RStudio to do the package building. However, it seems I cannot make it find the 'otherpackage'. Where do I set this under Windows/RStudio?

Anyone can give a quick hint, please?

Comment: What is the package required?

Comment: minpack.lm (no version conflict, if I see it correctly)

Comment: Do you have R studio pointing to your library that contains minpack.lm?  I've found when using R studio with different versions R the library isn't being pointed to correctly.  You could also try re-installing minpack.lm in the current version of R you're using.

Comment: How are you checking the package?